# infinite series and proof of sum using induction.

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

> Consider the series:  $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{(i+1)!} $$  Make a
>   guess for the value of the $n$-th partial sum and use induction to prove
>   that your guess is correct.

I understand the basic principles of induction I think I would have to assume the n-1 sum to be true and then use that to prove that the nth sum is true. But I have no idea how to guess what the sum might be? Doing the partial sums indicates that the series converges at possibly 1.

Comment: You could write down a few partial sums and guess.

Comment: Ok so I think I worked out that the value of the nth partial sum is ((i+1)!-1)/((i+1)!. But can anyone give me a tip as to how I start my induction proof?

Comment: Your $n^{th}$ partial sum should probably have an $n$ in it. Otherwise, you're saying that the expression you got is true regardless of how many $i's$ you add up

Comment: Woops sorry, the i's above are all supposed to be n

Comment: Ok so supposing that's the correct answer, first show it's true for your base step $n=1$. Then supppose it's true for some $n$ and now try and prove it's true for $n+1$.

Comment: **Hint:** Add and subtract $1$ in the numerator. :-$)$

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a guess, you should begin by calculating some partial sums:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^1\frac{i}{(i+1)!}&=\frac12\\\\
\sum_{i=1}^2\frac{i}{(i+1)!}&=\frac12+\frac2{3!}=\frac12+\frac13=\frac56\\\\
\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{i}{(i+1)!}&=\frac56+\frac3{4!}=\frac56+\frac18=\frac{23}{24}\\\\
\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{i}{(i+1)!}&=\frac{23}{24}+\frac4{5!}=\frac{23}{24}+\frac1{30}=\frac{714}{720}=\frac{119}{120}
\end{align*}$$

Now look at that sequence of partial sums: $$\dfrac12,\dfrac56,\dfrac{23}{24},\dfrac{119}{120}\;.$$ The pattern of the denominators should leap out at you to suggest a conjecture as to the denominator of the $n$-th partial sum, and the likely relationship between the numerator and the denominator is even more apparent. Write down a conjecture of the form

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{(i+1)!}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}\;,$$

where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are some integer functions of $n$, and try to prove it by induction on $n$. Note that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{i}{(i+1)!}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{(i+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\;,$$

so this boils down to proving that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have:$$\dfrac{i}{(i+1)!} = \dfrac{(i+1)-1}{(i+1)!} = \dfrac{i+1}{(i+1)!} - \dfrac{1}{(i+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{i!}-\dfrac{1}{(i+1)!} \Rightarrow S_n = 1-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}\Rightarrow S=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} S_n = 1$$